# Why does my card only flip once then stop working?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FlashCard from "../components/flashCard";

function Study() {
  const globalStarred = [];

  const fakeData = [
    {
      term: "Random Name #1",
      definition: "def1",
      starred: "true",
    },
    {
      term: "Random Name #2",
      definition: "def2",
      starred: "true",
    },
    {
      term: "Random Name #3",
      definition: "def3",
      starred: "false",
    },
    {
      term: "Random Name #4",
      definition: "def4",
      starred: "true",
    },
    {
      term: "Random Name #5",
      definition: "def5",
      starred: "true",
    },
    {
      term: "Random Name #6",
      definition: "def6",
      starred: "false",
    },
  ];
  const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);

  const [cardIndex, setCardIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentCard, setCurrentCard] = useState(fakeData[0]);
  const [starred, setStarred] = useState(false);
  //data
  //have one card on the screen, switch the data in the card

  const nextCard = () => {
    console.log("next card");
  };
  const prevCard = () => {
    console.log("prev card");
  };

  const flip = () => {
    setFlipped(!flipped);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    const key = event.key;
    if (key == "f") {
      flip();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentCard(fakeData[cardIndex]);
  }, [cardIndex]);

  // Add event listeners
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    // Remove event listeners on cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <div onClick={() => flip()}>
        <FlashCard
          width={300}
          height={300}
          front={currentCard.term}
          back={currentCard.definition}
          flipped={flipped}
          starred={currentCard.starred}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Study;
```

It works the first time I hit the f key but nothing after that. I think it may be because the state isn't instantly updating. I am displaying a card on my screen. When I click the f key (or click on the card) I want to update the state and change flipped to !flipped. This will cause the page to re render and the  component to re-render with the updated flipped boolean. Please help me fix this!!

Comment: Are both `handleKeyDown()` and `flip()` called?

Comment: Have you tried setFlipped(prevState => !prevState)? This should make sure you are taking the most recent state.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a flip function, which is bound to an event.

The effect is flipping the state. So it checks if the flipped state is false, and if so it sets the flip state to true, thus flipping it.
`flipped = !flipped` would also work in this case.

And then re-rendering happens, with the flipped state set to `!flipped`.

```
    <div onClick={() => flip()}>
      <FlashCard
        width={300}
        height={300}
        front={currentCard.term}
        back={currentCard.definition}
        flipped={flipped}  //<<--- THIS MIGHT BE THE PROBLEM!!!<<<-- Needs changing to !flipped once flipped = true...
        flipped={flipped}
        starred={currentCard.starred}
      />
    </div>
```

But you can't do this, so you have to get the flipped state and pass it down.

```
      const flip = () => {
      setFlipped(!flipped);
    };
```

You can have a function that changes the value of the state based on some argument. So you could have it look at the event and see if it's a keydown event and if so change the state with `setFlipped`.

This function won't re-render, but that's fine because it's not bound to an element, just a listener. If you want to always listen for clicks, pass an empty array into useEffect instead of [] as your second argument and add a reference to whatever element you want to attach your listener to. The ref will be called whenever this component renders, which is exactly what we want here: constantly updating our clicked state based on whether we've clicked or not.

Here's what I came up with:

```
jsx import React, { useState } from "react"; 
import FlashCard from "../components/flashCard"; 

const Study = () => { 

  const globalStarred = []; 
  const fakeData = [ 
      { term: "Random Name #1", definition: "def1", starred: "true" }, 
      { term: "Random Name #2", definition: "def2", starred: "true" }, 
      { term: "Random Name #3", definition: "def3", starred: "false" }, 
      { term: "Random Name #4", definition: "def4", starred: "true" }, 
      { term: "Random Name #5", definition: "def5", starred: "true" }, 
      { term: "Random Name #6", definition: "def6", starred: null } 
  ]; 

  const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false); 
  const [cardIndex, setCardIndex] = useState(0); 
  const [currentCard, setCurrentCard] = useState(fakeData[0]); 

  const nextCard = () => {

      if (cardIndex + 1 < fakeData.length) 
          setCardIndex(cardIndex + 1); 
  }; 
  
  const prevCard = () => { 
      if (cardIndex - 1 >= 0) 
          setCardIndex(cardIndex - 1); 
  }; 

  const flip = () => {setFlipped(!flipped)};  

  const handleKeyDown = (event) =>{
      const key=event.key;
      if (key==="f"){
          flip()
      }
  }; 

  useEffect(()=>{
      setCurrentCard(fakeData[cardIndex]);
  },[cardIndex]);

  window.addEventListener("keydown",handleKeyDown); 

  return <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}> <div onClick={() => flip()}> <FlashCard width={300} height={300} front={currentCard.term} back={currentCard.definition} flipped={flipped} starred={currentCard.starred === "true"} /> </div> <button onClick={prevCard}>Prev</button> <button onClick={nextCard}>Next</button></div>; 

}; 
export default Study;
```

Comment: Please format the code, it is unreadable.
Also, are you calling flip() inside handleKeyDown after commenting it out.

Comment: Commenting out `const flip = () =>{setFlipped(!flipped)};` was a mistake. I have updated my post